# Delete data with ADODB VB6 and Access not work

Tags: ms-access, vb6, ms-access-2010

I am having a problem deleting data from an Access 2010 database with DELETE via ADODB. The database filename is `tiket.mdb` and the name of the table I am trying to delete from is `pemasukan`.

But, when I click the button that calls this code, the DELETE does not happen.

```
Private Sub btnHapus_Click()
   cari = txtNo.Text
db.Execute "DELETE * FROM pemasukan Where no='" & cari & "'"
MsgBox "Data telah di delete"

koneksi
    Set rs = New Recordset
    rs.Open "pemasukan", db, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic

    Set DataGrid1.DataSource = rs
    DataGrid1.Refresh
End Sub
```

Comment: What does "does not work" mean? Are you getting an error? What behaviour are you seeing?

Comment: So what are you seeing? Have you looked at the backend database? Can you confirm that the variable `cari` contains what you expect? Does the DELETE statement work if you issue it direct in Access?

Comment: I se MsgBox "Data berhasil dihapus!" but the Delete not working

Comment: Sorry, unless you are able to provide answers to all the questions I asked last time, I cannot help further.

Comment: Assuming db is an ADO Connection, how is it opened? Please edit your question to show the code that opens the connection.

Comment: First of all I would recommend putting Option Explicit at the very top of your code. That will show you undefined variables. Secondly, is 'no' a string or an integer? Thirdly, learn about what a recordset is, what a connection and what a command. I think you might be doing things in the wrong order there.